What define a tournament as a "Open"
I used to think an open tournament was by definition open to everyone who was willing to pay the entry costs, but it is clear that some "Open" tournaments are not.
So what is the definition?

i thought open is for any age group, any gender. maybe some restrictions on ratings

@cmgchess but there are women opens.

In the context of professional chess, something like Norway Chess (by invitation) or qualifiers would be "not open". So any event where there is no fixed number of entrants would be "open", which is typically most Swiss events (some may impose an upper limit due to space/safety considerations). It is also possible to have both open section and "not open" section in the same event.
